# Where is `AsmVerbose` or `IsVerboseAsm` set in LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm

I am learning LLVM backend. I would like to enable `IsVerboseAsm` for `AsmPrinter` on my new target machine so that I can print comments.

I tried to do this by referring to `Target/X86`. Because I noticed that on my target machine, `IsVerboseAsm` is always `false`, while for X86 it is always `true`.

However, I could not find any code to configure `IsVerboseAsm`. I traced it with gdb and found that the source of this data came from a macro under `include/clang/Driver/Options.inc` generated when LLVM compiled:

```cpp
CODEGEN_OPTION_WITH_MARSHALLING(prefix_1, &"-fno-verbose-asm"[1], fno_verbose_asm, Flag, f_Group, INVALID, nullptr, CC1Option, 0, nullptr. nullptr, nullptr, "-fno-verbose-asm", true, 0, CodeGenOpts.AsmVerbose, true, false, true, normalizeSimpleNegativeFlag, denormalizeSimpleFlag , mergeForwardValue, extractForwardValue, -1)
```

Further tracing is unnecessarily complicated for me. On the other hand, I also wonder why it would appear in such a place if this is target-independent code.

So, what keywords should I be looking at so I can know how to enable `IsVerboseAsm` for the `AsmPrinter` of the target machine I'm adding? I know I can always write some code to directly set the options in `TargetOptions` to `true`, but I'd like to know how other backends do it.